# SASS --watch issue on windows 8.1

Tags: windows, sass

I've got some issues with SASS. After updating the `.scss` file, the `.css` file won't update.

Lets say that this is my folder structure:

```
-scss
    -style.scss
-css
    -style.css

index.html
```

And I'm using this command from project root in cmd:

```
sass --watch scss/style.scss:css/style.css --style compressed
```

It compiles it the first time, but when I make some changes in the `.scss` file, it doesn't update.

I'm using:

```
win 8.1 64bit
ruby 2.0.0p481 64bit
Sass 3.4.2
```

How to make it watch for updates? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

**Update**: Tested the same thing on ubuntu 14.04 and it works just fine (however, on ubuntu I've installed the latest version of ruby - **ruby 2.1.2p95** )

**Update 2**: [Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1409)

Comment: Not certain what kind of answer you're expecting here.  It is a known issue that this version of Sass does not watch correctly on Windows (you're even linking to the issue on GitHub).

Comment: I was hoping that someone had the same issue and that he came with a workaround. Or maybe that someone can confirm that it will work if I downgraded the versions of ruby or SASS. Basically anything that would help.

Comment: Instead of waiting for someone to say "hey, downgrade your version", you could have tried doing that yourself.

Comment: @cimmanon Well, downgrading the version is obviously the last option. And I currently can't do it myself because I'm on vacation w/o my dev machine so I posted this question hoping someone had and fixed this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in Sass 3.4.2: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1409

It was fixed in Sass 3.4.3: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html#343_4_september_2014

If you're using Bundler, make sure your Sass version is not restricted to `3.4.2` in your `Gemfile`. Recommended line is `gem 'sass', '~> 3.4.3'`. The run `bundle update` within your project root.

If you're not using Bundler, simply run `gem update sass`.

Comment: Yes, I saw the update. Nice of them to fix the issue so fast :)

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this issue. I downgraded Sass to version 3.3.14 and it worked for me again. No idea why.

Using:
win 8.1 64bit
ruby 2.0.0p481 64bit

Comment: I downgraded to 3.4.1 and it also works. Seems to be a bug in 3.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and upon solution didn't helped. Looks like ruby on windows 8 has WDM (Windows Directory Monitor) problem and `--watch` command is not working properly.

I solved problem in this way:

> 1. Downloaded and installed Installed Ruby 1.9.3p550 - [Download link](http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p550.exe?direct)
> 2. Downloaded and installed Development Kit (which is required to install WDM) for Ruby 1.9.3 -
>      [DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20110712-1620-sfx.exe](https://github.com/downloads/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe)
> 3. Extract DevKit to path C:\Ruby193\DevKit
> 4. Run `cd C:\Ruby193\DevKit`
> 5. Run `ruby dk.rb init`
> 6. Run `ruby dk.rb review`
> 7. Run `ruby dk.rb install`
> 8. Then run `gem install wdm`

And after that, `--watch` command is working properly.

Hope this way will help someone.