# Command prompt won't update when I update my .scss files

Tags: ruby, windows, sass, compass-sass

I've installed Sass and Compass on Ruby and am trying to make Sass watch my `.scss` files. I've typed in the following to make this happen:

`sass --watch [sass directory]\style.scss:style.css`

Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPYcW.jpg

When I update the .scss file and save it, I check the command prompt and there are no updates. It just keeps saying ‘Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl + C to stop.”

What is the issue?

[This is the tutorial I followed.](http://www.impressivewebs.com/sass-on-windows/#comment-73492)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Compass you can do a `watch` on the root project folder that contains `config.rb`

```
$ cd /path/to/project
$ compass watch
```

For more info see Compass [help](http://compass-style.org/help/)

Comment: How will this help?  Compass is just a wrapper around Sass.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're doing nothing wrong, and are using the latest version of SASS, Selective Steve (3.4.2)

There seems to be a bug with this latest release where under certain circumstances `sass --watch` fails.

- Reported on their Github here:
  https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1409
- And also mentioned here:
  [SASS --watch issue on windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583360/sass-watch-issue-on-windows-8-1)

Comment: If this question is a duplicate of another question, this question should be closed as such.